# javascript make variables inside a function global

Tags: javascript, function, execution

I'm new to Java Script and here's what I'm stuck with.
I've been trying to make a variable inside my function global so that I could use it in the other parts of the code. Nothing seems to be working so far. Below is my code:

```
var json2="-";

var request = require("request");
var smallpie1 = 
"https://s3.amazonaws.com/vecareclientjson/user1/predictions.json";

var pre = {rejectUnauthorized: false,
       url: smallpie1,
       method: 'GET',
       json: true
};
function test1(){
    request(pre,function (error,response,body){
        json2 = JSON.stringify(body);
        console.log(json2);
    });
};
console.log(json2);

Output:
-
[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.231 seconds
```

I was expecting the content in the json to overwrite the json2 object.
The goal is to make the `json2` object inside the function `test1()` global.

Comment: Do you ever run `test1()` ?

Answer (score 1):

As other contributers are telling you, you must run the `test1()` function. You can do so by adding it to the bottom of your code, before logging the `json2` variable, such as:

```
var json2="-";

var request = require("request");
var smallpie1 = 
"https://s3.amazonaws.com/vecareclientjson/user1/predictions.json";

var pre = {rejectUnauthorized: false,
       url: smallpie1,
       method: 'GET',
       json: true
};
function test1(){
    request(pre,function (error,response,body){
        json2 = JSON.stringify(body);
        console.log(json2);
    });
};

test1(); // Here you call the function, which will modify json2
console.log(json2); // Here you print json2 current value
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have not yet run the function.

Answer (score 0):

Run the function test1 before console.